# How to combine useState hook with switch cases in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, switch-statement

Here is component with the array of items, counters val and spiceValue and rendering block with adding some quantity of spices for example. Every spice has own price, adding or removing by click on plus or minus. How to implement this logic according to best practices of react?

```
export const SpiceBlock = ({ isCalculated }) => {
  const [spiceQuantity, setSpiceQuantity] = useState(0);
  var val = 0;
  var spiceValue = 0;
```

Calling useEffect with passed val as argument in any part of this code could not to read val

```
useEffect((val) => {
  setSpiceQuantity();
}, []);
```

```
  const spicesCount = (event) => {
    const direction = event.target.dataset.direction;
    const dataSpice = event.target.dataset.spice;
    switch (dataSpice) {
      case "guarana":spiceValue = 21;break;
      case "zhen":spiceValue = 11;break;
      case "cinnamon":spiceValue = 33;break;
      case "tapioka":spiceValue = 41;break;
      default:return false;
    }

    if (direction === "plus") {
      val += spiceValue;
    } else if (val - spiceValue > 0) {
      val -= spiceValue;
    }
  };
 
  const spicesArr = [
    { name: "Guarana", data: "guarana" },{ name: "Zhenshen", data: "zhen" },
    { name: "Cinnamon", data: "cinnamon" },{ name: "Tapioka", data: "tapioka" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={`spiceItems ${isCalculated ? "calculated" : ""}`}>
      {isCalculated && spicesArr
        ? spicesArr.map((spice, index) => (
            <div className="counter" key={`spice${index}`}>
              <button
                className="counter__btn"
                data-direction="minus"
                data-spice={spice.data}
                onClick={spicesCount}
              >
                -
              </button>
              <label htmlFor="spice" type="text">
                {spice.name}
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="spice"
                  value={val}
                  disabled
                  className="counter__value"
                />
                {spiceQuantity}
              </label>
              <button
                className="counter__btn"
                data-direction="plus"
                data-spice={spice.data}
                onClick={spicesCount}
              >
                +
              </button>
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: set val as a state and add it as a dependency to your useEffect.  So that everytime you set the value of val the setSpiceQuantity function will be triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set val as a state and add it as a dependency to your useEffect. So that every time you set the value of val the setSpiceQuantity function will be triggered

```
const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setSpiceQuantity();
}, [val]);

if (direction === "plus") {
      setVal(val += spiceValue)
    } else if (val - spiceValue > 0) {
      setVal(val -= spiceValue)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but one mark: in setVal need to set without equal sign, like this setVal(val + spiceValue)

Answer (score 0):

Any variable that is not a state will disappear after rerender, it's better to store variables in the state

```
const [value, setValue] = useState()

const getValue = type => {
  switch (dataSpice) {
    case "guarana": return 21;
    case "zhen": return 11;
    case "cinnamon": return 33;
    case "tapioka": return 41;
  }
}

const spicesCount = (event) => {
  const direction = event.target.dataset.direction;
  const dataSpice = event.target.dataset.spice;
  
  const val = getValue(dataSpice);

  if (direction === "plus") {
    setValue(value => value + spiceValue)
  } else if (val - spiceValue > 0) {
    setValue(value => value - spiceValue)
  }
};
```

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="spice"
  value={value}
  disabled
  className="counter__value"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, good example but I can not adopted this decision for my code.